# How can i display a Foreign Key on a select tag in my django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm trying to **display some information on a SELECT tag on my template that passes through a for loop** and can't seem to find a how to. The examples I find on the internet aren't dynamics (from another table) and I'm really struggling on that. Bellow are my codes, hope you guys can help me on this.

This is my **models.py**

```py
class Books(models.Model):
    [...]
    category_cod_category = models.ForeignKey(
        'Category',
        on_delete = models.CASCADE
        )

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Books'

class Category(models.Model):
    category_name = models.CharField(
        max_length = 45
        )

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % self.category_name


    class Meta:
        db_table = 'Category'
```

This is my **views.py** and this bit of code is from another template where I have a button for editing.

```py
def edit(request,id):
    book = Books.objects.get(id=id)
    return render(request,'edit.html',{'edit_book':book})
```

This is my **template edit.html** where i need the category of the books to be displayed. Every other field is OK.

```
<form method="POST" class="post-form" action="/update/{{ book.id }}">
    {% csrf_token %}

    [...]

    <div class="container">
        <label>Categoria do Livro:</label>
        <select class="selectpicker form-control" data-live-search="true">
            {% for books in Books %}
                <option value="{{ edit_livro.category_cod_category}}">{{ edit_livro.category_cod_category}}</option>
            {% endfor %}                                
        </select>
    <div>

    [...]
```

Can you guys help me? Or send me a place where I can learn how to solve this?

Sorry for any misspellings, I'm not a native english writer.

Thanks!

EDIT: 
I'm using ModelForms for my insert template, It's listed below:

```py
class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = [ ...,'category_cod_category', ... ]
```

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you do not use a `ModelForm` here? This really makes working with models more convenient.

Comment: Not a specific reason, i'm just very new on django and don't know very well how to make things... If you have something to help me I would be grateful. 
Just realised that i'm using one but it's for my insert template... Don't know if can be used on this case

Comment: I would advise to first read this section: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/forms/modelforms/ it will automate constructing a lot of forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Step:1 
# Create url for views (listing, create, update)
urls.py

path(r'book-listing/', BookListView.as_view(), name='book-info-listing'),
path(r'book-info-create/', BookCreateView.as_view(), name='create-book-info'),
path(r'book-info-edit/<int:id>', BookUpdateView.as_view(), name='edit-book-info'),


# Step:2
# Create form for your model

forms.py

# You just need to set the queryset for your field of form, if you want to get the select tag for all your category

class BooksForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    self.fields['category_cod_category'].queryset = Category.objects.all()

    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = [ ...,'category_cod_category', ... ]


# Step:3
# Create views for your model

views.py

# For Listing a book info

class BookListView(generic.ListView):
    model = Books

    def get_queryset(self):
        books = self.model.objects.all()
        return books


# For Creating a new book

class BookCreateView(generic.CreateView):
    model = Books
    form_class = BookForm
    template_name = 'project_app/book-form.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(self.request)
        return redirect('book-info-listing')


# For Editing or updating a book

class BookUpdateView(generic.UpdateView):
    model = Books
    form_class = BookForm
    template_name = 'project_app/book-form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('book-info-listing')

    # get the object
    def get_object(self, *args, **kwargs):
        book_info = get_object_or_404(Books, pk=self.kwargs['id'])
        return book_info

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save(self.request)
        return redirect('book-info-listing')


# Step:4 Render form in your template

book-form.html

<form method="POST" class="books_form">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form.category_cod_category}}
</form>
```